# Google Search Console Products Schema Problem, We are a wholesaler bags

Tags: seo, google-search-console, schema.org, products

Today, I receive from Google a couple of errors in the products section of Google search console, In our store, the prices are missing because we are a wholesaler of bags, so we sell only to the company (B2B), and also we don't need review from the company, our website is https://www.ingrossoborseonline.com

Please, how can I resolve this problem?
Someone can help me find out a solution, please...

Thanks

[image: Google Search Console Products Schema Price, offer, reviews and aggregateRating problem, we are a wholesaler bags]

Answer (score 1):

It's a new report. Ignore the errors if you have good reason to exclude the information. It just means you are not eligible for the rich snippets that require that info. e.g. Google showing rices or review stars.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, these errors will not influence the ranking of the website ?

Comment: Structured Data has no direct influence on ranking. In this case the missing information can be used to create rich snippets.

Answer (score 1):

This web page has markup for **[16 separate types Product](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool#url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.ingrossoborseonline.com%2Fit%2F)**. This contradicts the following **[Google requirement for this type of Guidelines](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/product#guidelines)**:

> Use markup for a specific product, not a category or list of products.

In addition, your structured data has an obvious excess of the types used and corresponds to the **[following Google information](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/sd-policies)**:

> Important: Google does not guarantee that your structured data will
>   show up in search results, even if your page is marked up correctly
>   according to the Structured Data Testing Tool. Here are some common
>   reasons why:  ...The structured data is not representative of the main
>   content of the page, or is potentially misleading.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Prestashop do the same thing..